Finding partial derivative of a function containing dependent variables
This was the question in my math quiz
$F(x,y) = x^2 + e^{xy}$
$x$ and $y$ are dependent variables
$x = t^2$ and $y = sin(t)$
Find $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ at $t = \pi$
I know partial derivative has no meaning here because there are no independent variables here.
But our math professor says
$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{x}}$ can be considered to be 0
I'll be thankful if you could clear my confusion whether to consider it 0 or not.

If $x$ and $y$ are each functions of $t$, then they are clearly no longer independent. The question makes no sense. What does $\partial F/\partial x$ actually mean? You can't differentiate with respect to $x$ while holding $y$ fixed.

What they mean for you to do is this:

$\text{Find }\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\text{ where }F(x,y)=x^2+\mathrm e^{xy}\text{, at }(x,y)=(t^2,\sin(t))\text{, when }t=\pi.$

Treat $x$ and $y$ as independent variables, in $F(x,y)=x^2+\mathrm e^{xy}$, to thus find $\tfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ without any concern about $t$.
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial (x^2+\mathrm e^{xy})}{\partial x}$$
Having done that, you can then evaluate it along the path $(x,y)=(t^2,\sin(t))$.
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(t^2,\sin(t)) =\left.\dfrac{\partial (x^2+\mathrm e^{xy})}{\partial x}\right\vert_{(x,y):=(t^2,\sin(t))}$$
And in particular, do so at the point when $t=\pi$, so $(x,y)=(\pi^2,\sin(\pi))$
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(\pi^2,\sin(\pi)) = \left.\dfrac{\partial (x^2+\mathrm e^{xy})}{\partial x}\right\vert_{(x,y):=(\pi^2,\sin(\pi))}$$

Remember : perform the substitutions after the partial derivations.

I do not think it is $0$, since:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial y/\partial t}{\partial x/\partial t}=\frac{\cos t}{2t}$$
The value is only $0$ at $t=\frac {\pi}2$, which is not.
To calculate your answer, we can take the approach:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2x+ye^{xy}=2\pi^2+(\sin \pi) e^{\pi\sin \pi}
$$

Oh, I mistyped. Thanks for pointing it out.
